# Protecting Data/Storage With a Better Data/Backup System

Tags: macos, hard-drive, backup, raid, nas

I've been putting up upgrading my system for data/storage/backups and I really want to deal with this as soon as possible.

My Current System:
Apple Macbook Pro (OS and Applications

External Hard Drive - My Data Drive (music, photos, movies, documents, etc)

Apple Time Machine - Backups (It's been overheating for a while now)

I would like to upgrade this to something like a NAS for my Data Drive with some type of RAID Mirroring (need help here) and also want to replace the Time Machine but I don't know what to do for that yet.  I just want tons of protection and backups so I never have to worry about losing any files even if they are only 2 hours old.

Answer (score 0):

Apps can be re-installed relatively easily, and if you haven't customized the System folder (or installed homebrew or other UNIX-y things), the OS can be easily re-installed too.  To me, the most important backups are your files and preferences.

You can move most of your files into iCloud.  I think you can upgrade from 5GB to 20GB for $1/month, which is fine for "normal" files and preferences, and even reasonable iPhoto libraries.  If you have large video or photo projects, you'd need to buy more storage, or look elsewhere.

iTunes Match (aka, iCloud Music Library) is only $25/year and can handle ALL your music, separately from the regular iCloud storage.

It might be a little tougher to move your Preferences (and other important ~/Library folder items, like "Application Support") into iCloud, but I think it can be done with symlinks.  You might be better off using DropBox or something similar for the Library folder, though, so you don't get tangled up with those symlinks.

Comment: Just realized that I was really only addressing the "disaster recovery" aspect of backups.  You might certainly want other file-recovery features, like restoring old versions of a file, or to recover an accidentally-deleted file. I don't think iCloud helps with this, but other similar solutions (like DropBox) do, at least for the restore-old-version feature.  But, why not use Time Machine for both of these file-recovery use-cases?  USB drives are cheap, and some are bus-powered making connections very simple and making the drive very portable.